# Is it possible to use a custom Class in Properties.Settings.setting

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, settings.settings

I know that it is possible to use settings to store some default values or user settings of program.

But I need to make a setting that can hold a class that I wrote myself. Is this possible? I can't see the classes I made myself, in Type or Browse... column of Settings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It supports the basic data types + All you types. You can store your object into XML or implement serialization to save through IO to any format as well. Browse through the namespace of your project to your type. Use the Visual interface: Project Properties -> Setting -> Type Column -> Browse... -> Navigate your Project Namespace and select your desired type.

BTW, rebuild solution/project if you can't see your classes there.