# Using a custom class for a setting - can't browse to the custom class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, settings

I see in places like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995055/is-it-possible-to-use-a-custom-class-in-properties-settings-setting) that you can use a custom class for "Properties->Setting".

I saw somewhere a screenshot that shows a "Browse" at the bottom of the "setting->Type" column. I do not have one:

[image]

I am using:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit)
Version 17.0.1

How can I use a custom class as a setting?

Comment: Same problem here. Not found an answer either. :(